# Regex : add spaces to format a field

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I have this input :

```
P_200:E2:0.0200
```

I need this output:

```
P_200                   E2  0.0200
```

That is, the first ":" is replaced by spaces, such that the total length of the field is 24 characters, and the 2nd ":" is replaed by "\t"

I can select and replace the last ":" , using something like :

```
:(?=[^:]*$)
```

I can also select the part till the first ":" , by using something like :

```
^[^:]+:
```

but i have no idea how to replace it such that it is formatted and has 24 characters (extra filled with spaces)

Comment: willling to do it on a text-editor, specifically sublime text 3

Answer (score 1):

#### Notepad++

Using N++ it could be done with one regex and replacement string but with pushing <kbd>replace all</kbd> button two times:

Regex:

```
^(?(?![^:]{24})([^:]*):([^:]*):|(.{24})[^:]*)
```

Explanation:

```
^                 # Match start of input string
(?                # Start of conditional statement (cs:1)
    (?![^:]{24})    # If there isn't 24 characters before colon
    ([^:]*):        # Capture 1st field value and next colon
    ([^:]*):        # Capture 2nd field value and next colon
    |               # Else
    (.{24})[^:]*    # Capture 1st 24 chars and match extra ones
)                 # End of conditional statement (cs:1)
```

Replace with:

```
(?1\1                        \:\2\t:\3)
```

This benefits from conditional replacements of [BEF string syntax](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/boost_format_syntax.html). If first capturing group exists, replacement string would be `\1                        \:\2\t` that has 24 space characters in between otherwise it will replace it with a back-reference to third capturing group `\3`

[image]

#### Sublime Text

In Sublime Text taking two find / replace steps are needed:

**Step #1**

Find What:

```
^(?(?![^:]{24})([^:]*):([^:]*):)
```

Replace with:

```
\1                        :\2\t
```

**Step #2**

Find What:

```
^(.{24})[^:]*
```

Replace with:

```
\1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python:

```
import re
text = 'P_200:E2:0.0200'
print(re.sub(r'^(.+?):(.+?):(.+?)$', '\g<1>' + ' ' * 24 + '\g<2>\t\g<3>', text))
```

With `sed`:

```
echo "P_200:E2:0.0200" | sed 's/^\(.\+\?\):\(.\+\?\):\(.\+\?\)$/\1                        \2\t\3/g'
```

In text editors with regular expression support:

Search: `(.+?):(.+?):(.+?)`
Replace to: `\1                        \2\t\3`

The numeric placeholders "`\1`", "`\2`" and "`\3`" sometime are in different format like "`$1`", "`$2`" and "`$3`" depends on the editor you used.

Comment: it will give me 24 spaces after \1 , i want the whole field to be 24 characters